# How to set route in ExpressJS to catch all deep route when html5Mode(true) is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I'm using angular ui-router in the frontend and have set html5Mode to true:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',              
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {           
    $stateProvider                                                                        
    .state('app', {                                                                       
        url: '/',                                                                     
        views: {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            'content': {                                                                                                                                    
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/landing.html',                  
            },                                                                    

        }                                                                         
    })                                                                            
    .state('app.home', {                                                          
        url: 'home/:username',                                                                                                                            
        views: {                                                                
            'content@': {                                                       
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/home.html',                     
                controller  : 'HomeController',                                 
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    })
    .state('app.help', {                                                          
        url: 'help',                                                                                                                            
        views: {                                                                
            'content@': {                                                       
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/help.html',                     
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    });                                                                         

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');                                          

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({                                               
        enabled: true,                                                          
        requireBase: false                                                      
    });                                                                         
}])
```

Then in the backend I have set Express to catch all page request:

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers/static'));
```

./controllers/static.js looks like this:

```
router.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/../../public');                                                                      

router.get('/*', function(req, res) {               
    res.sendFile('public/layouts/index.html');                                                 
});
```

These work fine for pages that's one level deep, for example, I can refresh localhost:3000/help, however, it doesn't work for pages that's more than one level deep, refresh **localhost:3000/home/myuser** will fail with error like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to make refresh work on all routes? I tried router.get('*') but it doesn't work either.

It worked fine when I turn of html5Mode.

The Express version used is 4.13.3